# Преобразовать время в секундах в дату

Tags: javascript

Запрос к АPI возвращает json, в нем есть свойство в котором содержится время в таком виде

> {time:1524624197}

Как его перевести в формат UTC? Нужно перевести его в нормальную дату.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуй:

```
new Date(твоя дата*1000)
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло!